# Why does "continue" not work in this instance of while loop?

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to learn unix and practicing loops. Can someone explain why the output is suspended after encountering `continue` statement?

Output suspends after `Count : 4` and I have exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Code:

```bsh
COUNT=0

while [ $COUNT -lt 10 ]
do
  if [ $COUNT = 5 ]
  then
     continue
  fi
  echo "Count : $COUNT"
  ((COUNT++))
done

echo "while loop finished"
exit 0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is rather simple: Your `continue` statement instructs the shell to immediately skip execution to the next loop iteration.

Unfortunately you thereby skip the `((COUNT++))` part, meaning that once `COUNT` reaches 5, it will never be incremented again, and the `while` condition never be met, so you are stuck in an endless loop from that point onward.

If, as @steeldriver assumes, you instead wanted to break out of the loop at a `COUNT` of `5`, the `break` statement would be the correct choice.

As a general remark, if you are interested in learning more on shell scripts, I would recommend [GreyCat&Lhunath's Bash Guide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide). Also, running your scripts through [`shellcheck`](https://shellcheck.net) (also available as standalone program on many OS repositories) can help identify syntax errors and the like.